# Added custom field to category and its not showing on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I want to add a picture on top of category name in frontend.  I tried creating a custom field for the category and adding a picture that way. I can't see anything I type in the custom textarea. I tried flushing cache and reindexing data.

Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <resources>
            <add_category_attribute>
                <setup>
                    <module>Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute>
            <add_category_attribute_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute_write>
            <add_category_attribute_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

mysql4-install-0.0.1.php

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Custom attribute',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));

$this->endSetup();
```

Comment: Can you post your template where you are trying to get the field by getCustomAttribute()?

Comment: I didn't try to get the field. Where can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code to get category attribute value.

app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/category/view.phtml

```
<?php if($_customAttribute = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getCustomAttribute()): ?>
    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_customAttribute, 'custom_attribute') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: When i try this code my products disappear and i still can't see the attribute value